# syntax error: insert } to complete ClassBody

Tags: java, android

I created a method and keep getting an error that I need to include a } at the end of my method. I put the } in and the error is still there! If I then delete that } the same error will pop up on a prior method; and that error wasn't there before. in other words, if i type the } on my most recent method then the error stays there and only there. if i delete it, it duplicates that error on my prior method.

```
private void putThreeBeepers() {
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    putBeeper();
    move();
}
putBeeper();
}
private void backUp() {
turnAround();
move();
turnAround();
   }
```

Comment: It's complaining about a missing } to terminate the class - is that in? Also, your formatting is broken - you're mixing tabs and spaces. Look at it, it doesn't look right at all.

Comment: the formatting got all screwy when i tried to copy and paste code, but have it stay in the "insert code here" area in this window.

Comment: can you provide the exact error messages from the compiler?

Comment: Would this be Karel the Robot? on Android? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You really want to go to the top of your file and do proper and consistent indention all the way to the bottom.

For example...

```
private void putThreeBeepers() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        putBeeper();
        move();
    }

    putBeeper();
}

private void backUp() 
{
    turnAround();
    move();
    turnAround();
}
```

Odds are, somewhere along the line, you are missing a }.  Your description isn't super clear, but if the code you posted is how you actually have it formatted in your file then odds are you just missed something somewhere... and poor indentation makes it very hard to spot.

The fact that the message is changing is confusing, but it is the sort of thing you see in these cases.

Comment: in my actual code, the formatting/indentation is perfect (i think...). I just had trouble transferring that code correctly to here.

Comment: Using Eclipse, try Ctrl+Shift+F (you may want to save a backup copy if the source is not under version control) which should format the source code.  Presumably any errors should crop up there (I don't use Eclipse so not sure what it will do if there are issues with the code).

Comment: Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody. I'm confused. Why is it even referring to it as a class? Isn't a method?

Comment: Eclipse is CTRL+SHIFT+P by default. Look under Navigate -> Goto -> Matching Bracket. It's called ClassBody because it's the BODY of the CLASS. The missing bracket is for the "class", not for any of its methods. (It's implicit since one of your methods is missing a '}', so the final '}' that is supposed to terminate the class just terminates a method.)

Comment: If you are on a Unix type machine (Linux, OSX, etc) or on Windows with Cygwin (which is free) do this: cat YourFileName.java | awk '{ for ( i=1; i<=length; i++ ) arr[substr($0, i, 1)]++ }END{ for ( i in arr ) { print i, arr[i] } }' | grep [{}] replace the YourFileName.java with the actual file name.  This will tell you how many { and } there are... if the number isn't the same then you are missing one :-)

Comment: You may have the indentation right, but a problem in the comments (any extra */ will cause that error in Eclipse)

Answer (score 5):

the error might be misleading. In my case i had incorrect/incomplete comment statements such as below which is broken lead to this error:

```
/*
//  */
*/
```

Fixing the comments fixed the error. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: In jsp look for unbalanced <!-- and --> too!

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be caused by a number of different problems. :(

In my case it was that I have forgotten to specify the type of two parameters in one of my methods declareations.
To fix I had to change this:
 onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase pDb, pOldVersion, pNewVersion)
{

}
to this:
 onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase pDb, int pOldVersion, int pNewVersion)

Answer (score 2):

It might be due to invisible Chars when copying code from PDF ebook.
Be careful of the little red dot '.'

Choose 'Select First Character' -> then delete it.

[image: Invisible Chars when copying code from PDF ebook]

Answer (score 0):

Also, the same error might occur if you accidentally write an if-statement outside of a method. I kept overlooking it since I was looking at the bracket-matching only.

Answer (score 0):

I just simply add another"}",makes as "}}",then problem solved

I didnt have to put anther "}" for my other java code exercise.

Im a java beginner,I've come across same problem so I searched online found this thread.Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Turned out to be a very fundamental oversight.
I was having the properties of a class declared like this:

```
private Texture foo;
private Sprite bar;
foo = new Texture();
bar = new Sprite();
```

The mistake was i had been instantiating the foo and bar variables outside the functions 
of the class. When I put the

```
foo = new Texture();
bar = new Sprite();
```

into their proper functions (like below), the error went away.

```
private Texture foo;
private Sprite bar;
// function
public void instantiateVariables(){
foo = new Texture();
bar = new Sprite();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error due to a missing `<%`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps.

1. Just copy paste your code in notepad
2. Remove copy from Java file
3. Again copy notepad and paste into Java file.
4. An error will be gone.

Comment: kind of wired things, but worked for me. I used notepad++ though

Answer (score 0):

This question have already accepted answer but still there are some other problems where it occurs (like even though all statements are there correctly sometimes we will get this issue) and there are solutions too.

Recently I came across like this situation in eclipse workspace.

The solution is

1. Take the back up of that java file.
2. Remove the java file from that location and do the build/compile
3. Paste the file in the same location and do the build/compile
4. If the above step 3 does not work create new file and paste the content/code from backup file and do the build/compile
5. If the above step 3&4 both are not working then type the code of that file manually end-to-end and do the build/compile

Answer (score 0):

If this error comes in jsp, look for the braces. if open or close braces are missing, we will get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I have just added {{ and }} to make it work
I dont know why it happed but it suck

Comment: be sure to read the other answers to this question. Top answer already revealed a missing curly bracket. It would be helpful for others if you expanded your answer and revealed where you added the {{ and }}